# How can I create a Deep Learning Model for 2D input and output?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a project about deep learning. I have a array with shape (101,3) and output with shape (101,3). It means each row in input data is related to same line row in output data. My purpose is creating a deep learning model for traning my dataset. I made some research and I found a few example about it. One of them is at this [link](https://stackabuse.com/solving-sequence-problems-with-lstm-in-keras-part-2/). I need a many to many model as I understand but I don't know how to create it. Please can you help me about it? How can I create this model or is there any resources which you can suggest.

Comment: You have 101 rows and 3 columns in your entire dataset or each data has (101,3) shape?

Comment: Yes my entire data is 101 rows and 3 columns as named input_data and 101 rows 3 columns for output_data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this which you may have to change based on network performance,

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

model = Sequential()

# encoder layer
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences= True, input_shape=(101, 3)))

# decoder layer
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(3)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

print(model.summary())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something as follows. Please start your journey from this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner). You can play removing some layers below or adding more layers and see how your results are changing.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu',input_shape=(3,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])
```

#### model architecture is as follows

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 128)               512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 32)                2080      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 99        
=================================================================
Total params: 10,947
Trainable params: 10,947
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```